# IPv4 in IPconfig internet connection

Tags: windows-7, internet, connection

IPv4 in my IPconfig ( windows 7 ) is not there. Does anyone know why? Can I reinstall IPv4?  Because of this I can't connect to the internet ( through  wifi or ethernet cable)

Comment: First, Welcome to Superuser, second, your post miss a lot of info, IPCONFIG output, Device Manager Screenshot we cant only guess what your system is doing whitout the proper information.

Comment: How are you connected to the internet, wired or wireless, are you using a router under your control?

Answer (score 1):

1. Click `Start` > `Control Panel` > `Network and Sharing Center`.
2. Right click `Local Area Connection`.
3. Click `Properties`.
4. Enable `Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)`.

   [image]
5. Click `OK`.
6. Open a `cmd` prompt.
7. Type `ipconfig /renew`.
8. Test your internet.

Comment: I got a message that said " Local Are Connection has no IP address" IPv6 and IPv4 were checked. I still can't connect to the internet    In IPCONFIG it does not show an IP Address and it does not show IPv4. It also says " Media disconnected" I'll send some screen shots.

Comment: @user466821 "Media disconnected" - Do you have another cable you can try? And the obvious - is your router powered on?

Comment: @user466821 Please edit your question and include 1. the output of `ipconfig /all` 2. A screenshot of the LAN adapter status (Right click `Local Area Connection`, click `Status`).

Comment: I receive my internet through a cable TV company. I am connected to a modem they gave me. I tried using a different cable. I tried moving the cable to different ports. I still can't connect to the internet.  The status is " no network connection"    I am unable to add screen shots because I don't have a high enough "reputation" on this system.

Comment: @user466821 have you tried `diagnose`? (Right click `Local Area Connection`, click `Diagnose`)

Comment: @user466821 has your internet ever worked with this cable modem?

Comment: Yes my internet has worked with this cable modem.

Comment: @user466821 Did you try the Diagnose as per my other comment?

Comment: When I click Diagnosis it says " Local area connection does not have a valid IP configuration."

Comment: @user466821 Try removing the ethernet connection and adding a new one.

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: @user466821 To delete https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733147%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: @user466821 To add http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/setting-home-network#1TC=windows-7